# can I connect the actor to a user case and its included use case?

Tags: uml, use-case

I have a use case that the actor will contact with, that use case includes two other use cases. The actor can contact with them as well.

So my question can I connect the actors to those two use cases?

This the first image where the actor is just connected to the main use case,

[image]

this is the second image where the actor is connected to both the main use cases, and its included two use cases

[image]

is the second correct?

Comment: You are using functional decomposition with use cases. This is plain wrong. Go read Bittner/Spence or Cockburn to find out how to write use cases.

Comment: @ThomasKilian thanks, nevertheless, i still need an answer about my question

Answer (score 3):

If the included use case (UC) can be run only as inclusion/extension to some other UC then you do not connect the initiating actor to that UC (it is "automatically" included from the primary UC).

Yet there are two situations when an actor can be connected to included or extending UC:

1. The included/extending UC interacts with some other actor (not initiating one). Such actor will then be connected to the included/extending UC.
2. The included/extending UC can be run independently (i.e. can also be run as a separate UC rather than inclusion/extension to some other UC). In such case the actor that can initiate the UC directly will be connected to that UC (even if it is also connected to some UCs that include/are extended  by this UC)

I second the @ThomasKilian statement that your diagram creates a decomposition that definitely should not be depicted on UC.

Answer (score 0):

First

> Do not make things more complex for yourself

You should  explain your use case to your  father who has money but does not have a technology expertise...Think of use case as a business case which you want to persuate your father for giving you money to run it as busines.Can you "persuate" your father with this "recommendations level x" use cases?

> While drawing any use case just tell the big GOAL of user. Not 
>   execution order or other shits.Do not forget that you do not design your application while drawing use cases, you specify what kind of benefit/utility it gives the users.

I do not know your "Context"...But with over simplification it seems that you have just one valid use case "Make Recommendation".So jusy leave it as so...How user will do "Recommandation" (what-ever it is ) should be in "Make Recommendation" use case scenario TEXT. A use case can have many scenarious.

> Do not FORGET, use case analysis SHOULD involve WRITING
>   TEXT(Scenarious) more than just drawing.

It seems that you suffer from FUNCTIONAL DECOMPOSITION in use case analysis which many suffers.

> "a functional decomposition approach would break a use case into many
>   parts: Obtain Merchant Details; Process Foreign Exchange; Authorize
>   Payment; and Capture Payment".

How not to suffer from Function Decomposition:

Check
[Fowler, Use and Abuse Cases](http://martinfowler.com/distributedComputing/abuse.pdf)

Check [Is Login a Use Case? Use Cases vs Functional Decomposition](https://imprestige.biz/is-login-a-use-case-use-cases-vs-functional-decomposition/)

Check [Top Ten Ways Project Teams Misuse Use Cases](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/jul02/TopTenWaysJul02.pdf)

And Be Carefull You Should Not Have To Use Every Feature Of Uml

> "After all, these are part of the UML use-case notation, so aren't you
>   supposed to use them? **NO NO NO..**.

But you may think that

> you need them because "they help you to decompose use cases into
>   itty-bitty units of work."But you try to do this at WRONG Time with
>   WRONG tool.This decomposition  will not help you at this stage with this tool(use case)

Answer (score 0):

It is about conceptual modeling with use cases. Sure, should be "goal" focust, however it is nice to know about semantics.

Usually on does not specify multiplicities of association ends in an Use Case Diagram (UCD). Like everything in O.O. design, every binairy association has 2 ends. So also in an UCD. If you do not specify multiplicity, UML says; it is a mandatory 1 association. 
That could lead to problems of interpretation when communicating with your stakeholder about an UCD.

example:
Actor X starts Use Case A, but this use case always ("include") Use Case B.
So actor X is initiator of Use Case B.
Now we add an actor Y directly to Use Case B as initiator, and no multiplicities specified (so it is 1..1). Use case B cannot start without actor Y. Even if you include Use Case B, you need actor Y!  **Solution**: define multiplicity [0..1] at the association end near actor Y.

*notice*: we do not need actor X for starting Use Case B due to the "include" stereotype. if it was a Generalization (use case B is subcase of base use case A), then we should always need actor X to start use case B due to association inheritance! **Solution**: define multiplicity [0..1] at the association end near actor X.