# Can an actor be associated with extend or include

Tags: include, uml, extend

[My use case diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvEpS.png)

I'm not familiar with correct terms but is this possible? By associating the passenger actor to an include attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can I connect the actor to a user case and its included use case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675898/can-i-connect-the-actor-to-a-user-case-and-its-included-use-case)

Comment: Your `<<extend>>`s are the wrong way around. `Cash` is no UC (use predicate/subject[/object]).  Best you leave all that inc/ext away as you are trying functional decomposition, but UCs are about added value.